# Can ExpressJs compression compress on http request other than static file?

Tags: javascript, http, express, compression

I'm using express 4.x and have turned on compression middleware in my app.js like this:

```
var compression = require('compression');

var app = express();

app.use(compression());
app.use('/',               require('./static'));
app.use('/api/xxx',        require('./api/xxx'));
```

When I check in Safari web inspector, some files, like my app.js is indeed compressed, you can see a difference (though small) in file size:

[image]

but others like api requests are not:

[image]

There seems to be no difference in size, given that my server simply sends json on request, why the data transferred are not heavily compressed?

Answer (score 0):

it is because you need to set the compression level.

Read the documentation here: https://github.com/expressjs/compression

Mine is set for max compression like so:

```
// Compress content
app.use(compression({
    level: 9,
    memLevel: 9
}));
```